Why doesn't transferring an image to a texture object work for me?
I look at the guide on how to work with SFML and there it is clearly visible that it transfers the image file to a texture object. I get the following error: "There is no suitable user-defined conversion from "sf::image" to "const std::string""
Image heroimage; 
heroimage.loadFromFile("images/hero.png");

Texture herotexture;
herotexture.loadFromFile(heroimage);


Please [edit] you question to show your code as correctly formatted text (preferably as a [mcve]).  Also show all error message as text verbatim.

That code doesn't produce the error you claim it does. Please refer to [mcve] to learn what's expected here to ask useful questions.

In SFML, textures are loaded from files using the sf::Texture::loadFromFile method, which requires a file path as a string. Here's how you should do it:
sf::Texture texture;
if (!texture.loadFromFile("path/to/image.png")) {
    // Handle error
}

If you're trying to use an sf::Image object to create a texture, you need to use sf::Texture::loadFromImage instead. Here's an example:
sf::Image image;
if (!image.loadFromFile("path/to/image.png")) {
    // Handle error
}

sf::Texture texture;
if (!texture.loadFromImage(image)) {
    // Handle error
}

Make sure that in your code, you're using the correct method for the type of data you have (sf::Image or file path). If you intended to use a file path, ensure that you're passing a string to loadFromFile, and not an sf::Image object.
